# Would it make sense in batch learning to swap only part of the batch in every iteration

Tags: machine-learning

The context of this question is a simulated annealing process, but I would be also interested to know the effects on neural nets and other learning methods.

Say I have a dataset of 100k instances, and I'm training on a randomly selected batch of say 1k (meaning I'm evaluation performance on 1k when transforming my candidate model), what would be the effects of switching only a fraction of the batch at a time, rather then all of it?

Let me elaborate a bit on why I need this. I'm trying to optimize on the description length of my data given the model. Training on all data is of course computationally problematic, but batch training is also not good because my model is easily reaches a state where it loses the ability to generate some examples. Perhaps the conclusion is that my model is too strict...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by switching. But as a general rule if the subsample you use to train any learning system is randomly selected from the whole data set, you should be safe. Because as per random sampling the subsample will reflect the same distribution as the whole data set. If you do some ad-hoc subsampling that will affect the distribution, then no.

Answer (score 1):

Stochastic training of neural nets, ie. using random samples or batches, works because you get independent estimates of the gradient. If you only swap out a little of it, they will not be independent anymore, and training *might* thus fail.

For more info check [Leon Bouttou's "stochastic gradient descent tricks" paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/192769/tricks-2012.pdf).